# Best practice in Angular directive on a text input to format feet and inches

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am attempting to write a directive in Angular that takes a text input and formats the value as it's entered. I want to append the value with the " character to indicate inches unless the user types a [space], then it would replace the [space] character with the ' character to indicate feet. See below:

**So the user would enter:**
`5 7`

**and the input would format as:**
`5'-7"`

**Additionally, the user could enter:**
`709`

**and the input would format as:**
`709"`

I would also like the user to be able to backspace and it not consider the `'` or the `"`. Any direction would be greatly appreciated. Below is what I have so far but I'm still not quite clear on how best to approach this. 
Thank you,
-Zach

```
.directive('archUnits', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      var format = function(inputValue) {
        if (inputValue == undefined) inputValue = '';
        var formatted = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        if (inputValue != ''){
          formatted = formatted+'"';
          formatted = formatted.replace(" ","'-");
      }
        if (formatted !== inputValue) {
          modelCtrl.$setViewValue(formatted);
          modelCtrl.$render();
        }
        return formatted;
      }
      modelCtrl.$parsers.push(format);
      format(scope[attrs.ngModel]);
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: I guess you don't need an explicit call to `format(scope[attrs.ngModel]);` Do you have to apply similar formatting while loading any existing data as well? You might need a `$formatter` as well in that case

Comment: thanks, I removed the explicit call to format(). It still isn't working as expected though. it is always appended with " but when I enter [space] it doesn't replace with '-. Also, when using backspace, it doesn't let me backspace through the appended " character.

Comment: Do you mind providing a plunkr to play with this directive?

Comment: sure, here it is. http://plnkr.co/edit/rxCu39?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [This Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/o9MeEoTWQ9vDHQJsi4xw?p=preview) if this is what you want. Since a `'` and `"` are not a valid user input, you should not really be setting them back to view value. Either you can just use the modified model value, which would result in viewValue and modelValue out of sync, OR have a separate model for the formatted one and add some kind of `$watch` to the input model to apply the formatting.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      var format = function(inputValue) {
        if (inputValue === undefined) {return inputValue;}
        var formatted = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9 ]/g, '');
        if (formatted.length>0){
          formatted = formatted+'"';
          formatted = formatted.replace(" ","'-");
      } 
        return formatted;
      }
      modelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(format);
     // format(scope[attrs.ngModel]);
    }
```

**NOTE:** I would also suggest to add some `$validators` as well to make the field invalid for things like multiple spaces etc.